# How to cure injured player in Fifa Online 3?

Tags: fifa-online-3

I'm having a problem right now which is I can't cure my injured player in FIFA ONLINE 3. It is saying "suspend ranking mode x match" but I have already play like thousand match but still the same. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your own club. If you use a different club (temp) your player won't heal. 
Put him in reserve or sub, then play league or cup with your own club.

Comment: What do you mean by my own club?

Comment: A club, like a baseball bat. Put the injured player out of their misery, then use a Phoenix Down.

Comment: @Cong please disregard the other comment, while it is funny, it is obviously not true. What they mean by club is a team.

Comment: @DekoRevinio fine, fine, use a potion...